# Capitalize specific font size

Tags: tailwind-css

Inside a styleguide I'm actualy implementing I have to `text-transform:capitalize` whenever font size class `text-2xs` is utilized and asking myself, if it's somehow possible to realize within the `tailwind.config.js`file.

Actually tried to add the declaration similar to `lineHeight` without luck and also via `theme.extend` didnt't work (think due to misunderstanding yet).

My tries so far were:

Tailwind config:

```js
 [...]
 fontSize: {
      '2xs': ['8.625rem', { lineHeight: '1rem', textTransform: 'capitalize' }],
      xs: ['.75rem', { lineHeight: '1rem' }],
      sm: ['.875rem', { lineHeight: '1rem' }],
 [...]
```

Extend:

```js
 [...]
 theme: {
    extend: {
      '2xs': 'uppercase',
 [...]
```

Is there a way to realize something like that or do i have to do it another way outside the `tailwind.config.js`?

Thanks for any help here

Comment: I doubt if there is any way to do it via tailwind config. Maybe you will have to go with the class-based approach only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple css like

```
@screen 2xs {
    body {
        @apply uppercase
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Digvijay . Here  I'm actually looking explicitly for a `tailwind.config.js`appliable solution/way if technically possible.